# RJS Dynamic update ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rjs

I am using Rails 4.2.6/PostgreSQL and trying to make dynamic update in index that has form and generate by scaffold. I think I am doing right but having issue with render partial via rjs. Bellow is an error and code. Any idea? Or RJS still available in Rails 4??

**Server**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-21 18:50:59 -0700
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"Tim"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING     "id"  [["name", "Tim"], ["created_at", "2016-06-22 01:50:59.194072"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-22     01:50:59.194072"]]
   (63.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (37.6ms)
  Rendered users/create.js.erb (42.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 145ms (ActiveRecord: 65.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1:     <% @users.each do |user| %>
    2:       <tr>
    3:         <td><%= user.name %></td>
    4:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
  app/views/users/_user.html.erb:1:in     `_app_views_users__user_html_erb___2381841639716957386_70119033868960'
  app/views/users/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_create_js_erb__1865303298608397742_70119034321000'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#users").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>");
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

**app/views/users/index.html**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="users">
  <%= render @user %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

**app/views/users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I put something like `@users = User.all` in create action, it will renders all users twice as you can see in below image.
[image]

Comment: `_user.html.erb' page expects '@users' object with the expected users list but when you create a @user, you are not actually fetching the value for @users.

Comment: How can I add @users = User.all in create action or something else?

Comment: Have you tried putting @users = User.all just after `if @user.save` in `create` method? Why you are actually returning `@user` if you want to redirect to the `index` page rather than `show`?

Comment: You can also put a helper method in controller where you can define `@users`. "helper_method :all_users"

Then,

`def all_users
  @users = User.all
end`

Comment: Yes, I have put *@users = User.all* but it renders all of user list under the all of the user list.

Comment: I have attached image.

Comment: $("#users").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>"); change it to: `$("#users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>");` You cannot use append as it will add the returned html again to the DOM!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115256/discussion-between-masaaki-and-rajesh-omanakuttan).

Comment: Rajesh, Actually you were right. I have replaced .append with .html and kept @users = user.all under the if user.save in create action. Then this all works fine. You can make it as an Answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After tries and errors, I have confirmed there is an answer in Rajesh's comments. It was bit unclear in the process of tries but here is how I figure this out.

**create.js.erb**

*Before*

```
$("#users").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>");
```

*After*

```
$("#users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>");
```

**users_controller.rb**

*Before*
    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      format.js
    else
    .
    .
```

*After*
    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
    @users = User.all
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      format.js
    else
    .
    .
```

Then everything works fine.
These are actually very make sense for both, each for nil error and appended rendering behavior. Thanks for answering comment Rajesh. Next time, please try post it in answer section.